# Executing Javascript on HTML ready

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I'm basically creating a software that needs to execute a Javascript code depending on what page CefSharp is browsing.
The problem is that I need to execute this code as fast as possible but I can't find a way to do this using CefSharp.

The ideal would be to execute the Javascript code once the HTML is ready, but not when the tab has finished to load, it's a waste of time.
[Here is a little scheme to make you better understand.](https://i.ibb.co/DC0bKJF/Screenshot-1.png)

I already tried two things :

- `ExecuteScriptAsync()` : But this is executed way too early because the HTML isn't loaded yet, so it returns errors saying that the element my JS script want to work with is undefined.
- `ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded`: Self-explanatory, the JS is executed one the page is fully loaded.

The purpose of all this is to save as much execution time as possible.

Comment: Please make sure you've read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#when-can-i-start-executing-javascript The ExecuteScriptAsync doesn't dictate when the script is executed as your comment suggests,  it executes when you call it. I'd suggest you add a detailed example of the html and JavaScript you are using and add the JavaScript tag. The standard JavaScript options are available to you of course,  subscribe to DOM loaded event,  MutationObserver etc

Comment: @amaitland I understand this. What I wanted to do is executing JS when the HTML was ready. I found a solution.

Comment: That is exactly what I was suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution which consists in executing the script once the page is browsed using `ExecuteScriptAsync()`, then detecting when the DOM is ready to fire the script.

I tried this using jQuery first (`$( document ).ready(function() { ... });`), but the library wasn't even included yet when the Javascript file was executed.

So the working way was using pure Javascript instead of jQuery with `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ /*Main script here*/ });`.